# ffmpeg Output file #0 does not contain any stream when trying to access 1 of 2 audio streams

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv  -map 0:2 -c copy -strict -2  audio.mkv
```

Hi I have the above command. The output shows that there are 2 audio streams. I want to copy just the ac3 audio (actually I want to convert it but even this copy does not work). I have truncated the output print where there is metadata

NEW updated sample with full log which results in same message

```
ffmpeg -i input.mka -map 0:0 -c:a libfdk_aac   aac_out.m4a
ffmpeg version 2.7.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG 1.20.0) 20150311 (prerelease)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --incdir='${prefix}/include/ffmpeg' --arch=i686 --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu- --enable-cross-compile --enable-optimizations --enable-pic --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-libfaac --enable-encoders --enable-pthreads --disable-bzlib --disable-protocol=rtp --disable-muxer=image2 --disable-muxer=image2pipe --disable-swscale-alpha --disable-ffserver --disable-ffplay --disable-devices --disable-bzlib --disable-altivec --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --disable-vaapi --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=ac3 --disable-decoder=ac3_fixed --disable-encoder=zmbv --disable-encoder=dca --disable-encoder=ac3 --disable-encoder=ac3_fixed --disable-encoder=eac3 --disable-decoder=dca --disable-decoder=eac3 --disable-decoder=truehd --cc=/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ccache-gcc --enable-yasm --enable-libx264 --enable-encoder=libx264
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/volume1/..../input.mka':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.9 + libmatroska v1.5.2
    creation_time   : 2019-07-07 06:19:20
  Duration: 02:29:21.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 640 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), 640 kb/s
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 640000
      DURATION-eng    : 02:29:21.984000480
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 280062
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 716958720
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v35.0.0 ('All The Love In The World') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-07-07 06:19:20
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
Output #0, ipod, to 'aac_out.m4a':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.9 + libmatroska v1.5.2
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Comment: Share *full* log.

Comment: Hi Gyan. I've updated with a full log. in this case I used mkvtools to split the ac3 stream and tried to convert that. Same result

Comment: Your ffmpeg build is over 4 years old. Update to 4.1 or git master and check.

Comment: Wow... did not realize... Thanks. let me try... looks like that is the reason... i'll try on the original file with all the streams now

Comment: confirmed. had been using ancient ffmpeg version.